# Converted Web Project from .NET 1.1 to .NET 3.5 problems in code-behind with controls from aspx page

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am converting a .NET 1.1 ASP.NET web project to .NET 3.5 in VS 2008.  The conversion ran without any errors.  However, when I open up a code-behind file for an aspx page, the lines of code that reference controls on the page are not being recognized as existing.  I looked at a brand new .NET 3.5 Web Application and all the aspx files have an aspx.designer.cs file associated with them (as well as the aspx.cs file).  In the converted .NET 1.1 Web Application project, there are asp.resx files but no designer.cs file (but there is the aspx.cs file).  I am thinking that is the problem.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There were so many changes between .NET 1.1 and .NET 3.5, that your best bet would be to create a new project and then just create new pages for each of yours, and perhaps copy and paste from the old version to the new version, so that you have all the new changes.